# Should I use filters in VBA macro for Excel to select data for use within the macro?

Tags: vba, filter

newsih to coding VBA and have found myself building macros with filters to select certain data groupings within the data set to copy and do different things with.

Works ok but i feel like I am using an excel GUI feature instead of proper code.

If i progress to advance level VBA will i find myself using better coding tools to replace what i am doing  with filters? And if so what are some examples generally speaking?

Comment: Nothing wrong with applying a filter to copy certain data. Another option is to loop through your raw data and add target cells to a `Union` (collection of cells) and then copy the union.

Comment: One can use an ADO.Recordset for sorting and filtering, https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/10/vba-fabricate-ado-recordset-for-sorting.html